# async module apprears in package-lock and not appear in package.json

Tags: npm, eslint, package.json, package-lock.json

my project works but eslint show an err-message: 'async should appear in package.json dependencies'.
async appear in package-lock and not appear at package.json dependancies and I don't get how can it be that everything still works?

Comment: Can you share your package.json file? It looks like you forgot to run npm install. If that not works remove the node_module folder and run npm install again.

Comment: If the linter gives an error it will include a rule name - what is it? Did you read the relevant guidance? It's entirely normal for transitive dependencies to be in the lock file but not the package file.

Comment: import/no-extraneous-dependencies

Comment: I prefer not to npm i async if not necessary because it'll change me all package.lock and this is a company project .
I'm not sure if the right thing here is to disable eslint for one line.

Comment: Currently you're importing and using a _transitive_ dependency. If something else in your dependency tree updates its own dependencies such that `async` is no longer included, your code will suddenly stop working.

Comment: the code is working now, I just dont want to install async because it will change the versions in package-lock and change the whole project